# Three.js camera dome rotation

Tags: three.js

I want to recreate [this rotation effect](http://www.revolution.pn/pillars-of-panem) on mouse move in Three.js. What should I use to accomplish this? How to recreate this effect maximally similar?

Comment: orbit control allows similar movement

Comment: Not really. It stops when the camera is at the top point, over the object. Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of rotating the camera I figured, that I can get the needed effect if i just rotate all my scene objects. So I did the following:

```
canvas.on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var canvasWidth = canvas.outerWidth();
    var canvasHeight = canvas.outerHeight();
    var halfWidth = canvasWidth / 2;
    var halfHeight = canvasHeight / 2;
    var offsetX = canvas.offset().left;
    var offsetY = canvas.offset().top;

    // Main vars
    var mouseX = event.clientX - offsetX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - offsetY;

    var maxDegree = 20 * Math.PI / 180;

    var rotationZ = 0;
    if (mouseX < halfWidth) {
        rotationZ = -1* (halfWidth - mouseX) * (maxDegree / halfWidth);
    } else {
        rotationZ = (mouseX - halfWidth) * (maxDegree / halfWidth);
    }

    var rotationX = 0;
    if (mouseY < halfHeight) {
        rotationX = -1* (halfHeight - mouseY) * (maxDegree / halfHeight);
    } else {
        rotationX = (mouseY - halfHeight) * (maxDegree / halfHeight);
    }

    console.log(rotationZ, rotationX);

    mshFloor.rotation.set(rotationX, 0, rotationZ);
    mshBox.rotation.set(rotationX, 0, rotationZ);
    render();
});
```